# Image compression and resize in Java

Tags: java, image-compression

I need to be able to compress and resize images of type jpeg,gif etc in my Java code. Which library or class in Java should i use for compressing and resizing images ?

Thank You

Comment: whats is compress and resize images, are you talking about size in the pixels ???

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to do so.

You can either shell out to do it, or use a library like [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/).